# If statement run if empty string

Tags: javascript

If I do this in the console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.error')
```

An object of length 3 is returned.

If any of the property values are empty, then I do not want my if statement to run:

After getting frustrated with this (I was using `!= ''`) the internet told me to use `!== ""`

Here is the output for property in the object:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.error')[0]
""

document.querySelectorAll('.error')[1]
"some string"

document.querySelectorAll('.error')[2]
""
```

My newness to JS is probably apparent by my question so far. Is the "best" way to check for empty string to use what I have done `!==`?

```
<script>

var errorElems = document.querySelectorAll('.error');

for(i=0; i<errorElems.length; i++) {
    if(errorElems[i].textContent !== ""){
        dataLayer.push({
            "event": "errors",
            "eventCategory": "error messages",
            "eventAction": errorElems[i].id,
            "eventLabel": errorElems[i].textContent
            })
        };
    };
```

This appears to be working. But I'm one person checking in one browser (Chrome) on a desktop machine, if that matters.

What would be the most full proof (yet reasonably straightforwards) means to doing this? Is `!==` best test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its an empty string, `!== ""` is the way to go. If it can be undefined too (as it very much can happen when selecting DOM elements), then you should make a check like this:

```
if (typeof string !== 'undefined' && string !== "")
```

Answer (score 1):

empty values are parsed as false, if you just try

```
if (!errorElems[i].textContent) {
    ... // error handling code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Accepting the other answer for no other reason than timing.

Answer (score 1):

The Node.textContent property, as per its [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) can return a null value, so it would be better to test it with something like this:

```
var errorElems = document.querySelectorAll('.error'),
    errorElem;

for (i=0; i < errorElems.length; i++) {
    errorElemText = errorElems[i].textContent;
    if (typeof errorElemText === "string" && errorElemText !== "") {
        dataLayer.push({
            "event": "errors",
            "eventCategory": "error messages",
            "eventAction": errorElems[i].id,
            "eventLabel": errorElemText
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. So in that case could I not do: if (typeof errorElemText === "string" && errorElemText !== "") in a oner?

Comment: Of course. My bad. I pieced it together quickly. I edited my answer accordingly.